# Creating an array from recursive function in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, recursion

I want to create an array using recursion in Codeigniter. my function `make_tree()` in controller is :

```
function make_tree($customer_id,$arr = array()){

    $ctree = $this->customer_operations->view_customer_tree($customer_id);

    foreach($ctree as $v):
        echo $customer_id = $v['customer_id'];

        array_push($arr, $customer_id);

        $this->make_tree($customer_id);
    endforeach;

    var_dump($arr);

}
```

But the `var_dump($arr)` and `echo` results output like:

```
1013

array
  empty

array
  0 => string '13' (length=2)

11

array
  empty

array
  0 => string '10' (length=2)
  1 => string '11' (length=2)
```

How can I make a single array of all the three outputs, ie an array with elements `13,10,11`

Comment: I would say try passing the array to your function by reference instead of by value, this way it's working on the same array instead of creating a new one each recurse. basically initialize the array outside of the function then change the parameter '$arr = array()' to '&$arr'

Comment: Thanks .. It helped. Though its outputs lots of arrays, I getting my desired output in the last array.

Comment: it outputs the same array growing as you're dumping it on every function run. And you're welcome, glad it worked! remove the var dump in the function and just dump the original array after the function call.

Answer (score 1):

you need to send the array with the parameters otherwise a new array is created.

```
function make_tree($customer_id,$arr = array()){

    $ctree = $this->customer_operations->view_customer_tree($customer_id);

    foreach($ctree as $v):
        echo $customer_id = $v['customer_id'];

        array_push($arr, $customer_id);

        $this->make_tree($customer_id, $arr);
    endforeach;

    var_dump($arr);

}
```

PS: I don't know what you are trying to do exactly, but you probably need to add a stopping condition that is going to return the final array, unless you want to pass it by reference.

**UPDATE**

Here is one way to do it:

```
function make_tree($customer_id, &$arr)
{
    $ctree = $this->customer_operations->view_customer_tree($customer_id);

    foreach($ctree as $v):
        $customer_id = $v['customer_id'];

        array_push($arr, $customer_id);

        $this->make_tree($customer_id, $arr);
    endforeach;
}
```

and this is how you'd use it:

```
$final_array = array();
make_tree($some_customer_id, $final_array);
// now the $final_array is populated with the tree data
```

Comment: If I pass the array by reference `&$arr = array()`, it outputs ( or returns because I am going to return the array ) an array for every `$customer_id`. How can I generate a single array with all the `$customer_id` in it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use class scope.

```
class TheController {

private $arr = array();

function make_tree($customer_id){

    $ctree = $this->customer_operations->view_customer_tree($customer_id);

    foreach($ctree as $v) {
        $customer_id = $v['customer_id'];

        array_push($this->arr, $customer_id);

        $this->make_tree($customer_id);
    }

}

}
```